# AWS SES: If a user has previously marked an email as spam, will SES send them another email?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

When using AWS' SES. If a user marks an email as spam, will SES continue to send emails to them or does SES automatically add them to a suppression list?

Do we have to maintain our own suppression list for spam complaints and stop emailing them, or will SES handle this all for us?

I see that SES has a suppression list for hard-bounces, but it is not clear if they add people who mark emails as spam.

Comment: i too recently had the same problem, their advise is to create SNS notification system integrated with the Lambada function to detect hard bounces and manage it from there..

Answer (score 0):

Yep you have to maintain it yourself. As mahen3d said, you can attach SNS into it and then a Lambda function or something else to handle everything. If you use SES for newsletters, you can check out for example Sendy which has all of that built in.